# I Want To Save image in folder using django but i get this error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I Want To Save image in folder using django but i get this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /lunchpk/signup/
```

i need to fix any help will be appreciated

i also see more questions but i don't get correct answer so please answer my question don't add it to duplicate

here's my `views.py`

```
def signup(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = NewForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'Profile_Image' in request.FILES:
                profile.Profile_Image = request.FILES['profile_pics']
                # profile.Dish_Image = request.FILES['Dish_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = NewForm()

    return render(request,'html/signup.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})
```

Here is my `model.py`

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    Profile_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',null=True, blank=True)
    Dish_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Dish_pic',null=True, blank=True)
    Dish_Name = models.CharField(max_length=10,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

here is my `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

class NewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('Profile_Image','Dish_Image','Dish_Name')
```

Comment: You are checking for `Profile_Image` but after that you are using `profile_pics`. Is that correct? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: As long as you promise not to spam people with dish pics ;)

Comment: @Landcross You Are Correct Thanks!!

Comment: @Landcross can you please give me answer so i can accept

Comment: @UsmanShahzad Feel free to accept the answer from Michiel. He said the same. I initially posted mine as comment because I wasn't sure, but I missed the fact that you also posted the models and forms. No problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for a key `'profile_pics'` in request.FILES, but it's not there.

In a regular dict you'd get a KeyError. However, there can be multiple request parameters with the same name, so Django uses a MultiValueDict, which has its own MultiValueDictKeyError.

I think you want `request.FILES['Profile_Image']` instead of `request.FILES['profile_pics']`.